# Jquery & Ajax Form Validation function

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm trying to find a way to do a form validation with Jquery.
I currently have a problem with the validation function.
I am able to send the form without having anything in the input fields.
Could you please tell me the way to make it work.

```js
 function Valid(){
    var name1 = false;
    var name2 = false;
    var num = false;
    var mail = false;
    var msg = false;
   
     if (document.myForm.name.value ==="") {
          $('#name1').addClass('has-error');
          $( "#name2" ).click(function(){$("#name1").removeClass('has-error');});
          name1 = false;}
        
     if (!/^[a-zA-Z]*$/g.test(document.myForm.name.value)) {
          $('#name1').addClass('has-error');
          $('#name2').click(function(){$('#name1').removeClass('has-error');});
          name2 = false;}
    
    if (document.myForm.num.value.length < 17){
          $('#num1').addClass('has-error');
          $( "#num2" ).click(function(){$("#num1").removeClass('has-error');});
          num = false;}
    
    if (document.myForm.email.value === "") {
          $('#email1').addClass('has-error');
          $( "#email2" ).click(function(){$("#email1").removeClass('has-error');});
           mail = false;}
    
    if (document.myForm.message.value === "") {
          $('#msg1').addClass('has-error');
          $( "#msg2" ).click(function(){$("#msg1").removeClass('has-error');});
           msg = false;} 
  }// END VALIDATION
  
  
   function SubmitFunction(){
          if(Valid()){
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url:"../php/process.php",
              data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
              success: function(msg){
                $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                $("#msgsuccess").delay(500).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
                }    
          });//End 
         }
        }//End SubmitFunction
```

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: Your function is not returning anything. You are just setting the variables but the function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `return false;` to all your if-statements, and use `return true;` at the bottom.

Also, **always** do your validation twice, server-side and client-side. Client-side isn't nessecary, but **serverside is**.

**Edit:** Also, please note, after each return, your function just stops working. So if for example input 1 and 4 wasn't filled in, it will return false at input 1, and it won't check input 4 until next time you submit it and input 1 being filled in.

**Edit 1:** Which can be eliminated by doing it this way:

```
 function Valid() {
         var name1 = false;
         var name2 = false;
         var num = false;
         var mail = false;
         var msg = false;
         var error = false;

         if (document.myForm.name.value === "") {
             $('#name1').addClass('has-error');
             $("#name2").click(function() {
                 $("#name1").removeClass('has-error');
             });
             name1 = false;
             error = true;
         }
         if (!/^[a-zA-Z]*$/g.test(document.myForm.name.value)) {
             $('#name1').addClass('has-error');
             $('#name2').click(function() {
                 $('#name1').removeClass('has-error');
             });
             name2 = false;
             error = true;
         }
         if (document.myForm.num.value.length < 17) {
             $('#num1').addClass('has-error');
             $("#num2").click(function() {
                 $("#num1").removeClass('has-error');
             });
             num = false;
             error = true;
         }
         if (document.myForm.email.value === "") {
             $('#email1').addClass('has-error');
             $("#email2").click(function() {
                 $("#email1").removeClass('has-error');
             });
             mail = false;
             error = true;
         }
         if (document.myForm.message.value === "") {
             $('#msg1').addClass('has-error');
             $("#msg2").click(function() {
                 $("#msg1").removeClass('has-error');
             });
             msg = false;
             error = true;
         }
         if(error === true) {
             return true;
         } else {
             return false;
         }
     } // END VALIDATION

 function SubmitFunction() {
         if (Valid()) {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "../php/process.php",
                 data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
                 success: function(msg) {
                     $("#myModal").modal('hide');
                     $("#msgsuccess").delay(500).fadeIn(500).delay(
                         1000).fadeOut(500);
                 }
             }); //End 
         }
     } //End SubmitFunction
```

What this does is, it sets the error variable to false at the initialization of the function, but each time there is an error, it sets it to true. At the end of the function simply check if the error variable is true, if not, return false, if yes, return true.

Comment: A better way would be to check all the variables at the end, and if any are false, `return false`, else `return true`

Comment: @AngelJosephPiscola I just did it that way in another edit, I think we were at the same time.